# Trying to regenerate thumbnails in wordpress but get an error saying the original file is not found, file is definitely on the server

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Trying to regenerate thumbnails in wordpress but get an error saying the original file is not found, the file is definitely on the server in the location it should be.

I've checked the metadata and everything looks ok there as well.

This is really frustrating, anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, some of the images had wp-content/uploads/ at the start of the filename in _wp_attached_file in the metadata when that shouldn't have been there. Deleted that and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to bad permissions.

Check if that original image has the same permissions as the next original image and set them correctly.

Comment: Thanks but I checked that as well and they're correct.